# Using Jinja Template inside the value attribute of a text input tag

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to design a web page with web-framework flask. This is the basic representation of the problem I faced.

**app.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('main.html', value="Utkarsh Prakash") 

@app.route('/approved', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def approved():
    return "Done"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = False, threaded=False)
```

**main.html**

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <FORM action = "/approved" method = "POST">
            {{value}}
            <INPUT type="text" name="text" value={{value}}>
            <INPUT type = "Submit">
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I just want the value which I am rendering from my flask code to be passed as predefined value of my text input file. Although {{value}} is containing both the words "Utkarsh Prakash", my input text field only contains one word, i.e., "Utkarsh".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtjQl.png)

How can I display both the words in the input text area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in your `main.html`, you didn't quote the attribute value, so the result of your template is

```
<input type="text" name="text" value=Utkarsh Prakash>
```

Just change your template so it has `value="{{ value }}"`

```
<input type="text" name="text" value="{{ value }}">
```

edited code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "/approved" method = "POST">
            {{value}}
            <input type="text" name="text" value="{{ value }}">
            <input type = "Submit">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

One more thing, please change all the uppercase `html` tags to lower case.